# Issue with using std::conditional in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, conditional-statements, c++17, static-polymorphism

I am trying to define a template class with non-type template parameter. I then determine the type of the member of this class from this template parameter using `std::conditional`. I am running into some compile time errors.

Below is the MWE. In this MWE, I am trying to make the member, `FiniteElementList`, of template class, `Mesh`, either `std::vector` or `std::list` based on the condition being true (structured) or false (unstructured) respectively. The class, `Mesh`, contains some member and friend functions that are only declared for the moment and might be defined at a later stage.

**MWE**

```cpp
// c++ standard library headers                                                                                                                                                  
#include <list>         // std::list                                               
#include <type_traits>  // std::conditional                                        
#include <vector>       // std::vector                                             
                                                                                     
// (un)structured flag                                                             
enum class StructuredUnstructured { kStructured = true, kUnstructured = false };
                                                                                     
// (un)structured mesh                                                             
template <StructuredUnstructured is_structured>                                    
class Mesh {                                                                       
  using Element = double;                                                          
  using FiniteElementList =                                                        
      typename std::conditional<is_structured ==                                   
                                    StructuredUnstructured::kStructured,           
                                std::vector<Element>, std::list<Element>>::type;
                                                                                     
 public:                                                                           
  // constructors                                                                  
  Mesh() = default;                                                                
  Mesh(const Mesh& m) = default;      // copy constructor                          
  Mesh(Mesh&& m) noexcept = default;  // move constructor                          
                                                                                     
  // assignment operators                                                          
  Mesh& operator=(const Mesh& m) = default;      // copy assignment                
  Mesh& operator=(Mesh&& m) noexcept = default;  // move assignment                
                                                                                     
  ~Mesh() = default;                                                               
                                                                                     
  void Indexing() {}                                                               
                                                                                     
  void Properties() {}                                                             
                                                                                     
  friend Mesh ReadMesh() {}                                                        
                                                                                     
  friend void WriteMesh() {}                                                       
                                                                                     
  friend void WriteMeshVTK() {}                                                    
                                                                                     
  private:                                                                          
    FiniteElementList finite_elements_{};                                            
};                                                                                 
                                                                                     
int main() {                                                                       
  Mesh<StructuredUnstructured::kUnstructured> unstructured;                        
  Mesh<StructuredUnstructured::kStructured> structured;
}
```

**Compilation:**

I am trying to compile with clang compiler as follows

`c++ -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++17 mesh_structure.cpp -o mesh_structure`

And I run into the following errors

```
mesh_structure.cpp:34:15: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
  friend Mesh ReadMesh() {}
         ~~~~ ^
mesh_structure.cpp:46:45: note: in instantiation of template class 'Mesh<StructuredUnstructured::kStructured>' requested here
  Mesh<StructuredUnstructured::kStructured> structured;
                                            ^
mesh_structure.cpp:34:15: note: previous declaration is here
  friend Mesh ReadMesh() {}
         ~~~~ ^
mesh_structure.cpp:36:15: error: redefinition of 'WriteMesh'
  friend void WriteMesh() {}
              ^
mesh_structure.cpp:36:15: note: previous definition is here
mesh_structure.cpp:38:15: error: redefinition of 'WriteMeshVTK'
  friend void WriteMeshVTK() {}
              ^
mesh_structure.cpp:38:15: note: previous definition is here
3 errors generated.
```

Strange enough, the code compiles if I remove the second line, `Mesh<StructuredUnstructured::kStructured> structured;`, from `main()` function. I don't quite get what went wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The same free `friend` functions will be defined for each instance of the class template. Shouldn't they be depending on a non-type template parameter too? It's hard to say exactly how though since the functions are incomplete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not with `std::conditional`. Lets first look at a much simpler case with same problem:

```
template <bool>
struct foo {
    friend void bar () {};
};

int main()
{
    foo<true> x;
    foo<false> y;
}
```

`bar` is defined twice, hence the error:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'struct foo<false>':
<source>:9:16:   required from here
<source>:3:17: error: redefinition of 'void bar()'
    3 |     friend void bar () {};
      |                 ^~~
<source>:3:17: note: 'void bar()' previously declared here
```

To define it once, move the definition out of the templates definition:

```
template <bool>
struct foo {
    friend void bar ();
};

void bar() {}

int main()
{
    foo<true> x;
    foo<false> y;
}
```

Next, another issue is that you are trying to declare a `Mesh<kStructured> ReadMesh()` and a `Mesh<kUnstructured> ReadMesh()` (within the template definition the name `Mesh` refers to `Mesh<is_structured>`, except some special cases).

Thats not going to work unless you make `ReadMesh` a function template. You cannot overload based on return value alone. Once `ReadMesh` is a template, you can befriend only the matching specialization like this:

```
template <bool> struct foo;

template <bool x> foo<x> bar() {}

template <bool x>
struct foo {
    friend foo bar<x> ();
};

int main()
{
    foo<true> x;
    foo<false> y;
}
```